# ORM: Invoices. What is the v14 equivalent of register_payment from v10?

Tags: python, odoo

In Odoo 10 , there is a function register_payment which Reconcile payable/receivable lines from the invoice with payment_line . I want to get this fonctionnalité in Odoo 14.

Any help please?

```
account_invoice_ids = fields.One2many('account.move', string='Invoices')
account_move_id = fields.Many2one('account.move')

self.account_invoice_ids.register_payment(self.account_move_id.line_ids.filtered(lambda x: x.account_id.internal_type in ('receivable', 'payable')))
```

Comment: In Odoo 14 there is a method `action_register_payment` in `account.move` which will open wizard to register payment. And in `account.payment.register` there is a method `action_create_payments` to register the payments

Comment: @Adam Strauss, the function action_register_payment generate a wizard , but I need to register payment automatically.